# Why does chart of radiative decay modes appear in two different conventions (x and y axis switched) for english and french versions in wikipedia?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Why does chart of radiative decay modes appear in two different conventions for english and french versions in wikipedia ?

Which one is more academic ?

On english version, the Z number is in x axis, the N is in y axis :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay#/media/File:Radioactive_decay_modes.svg

[image]

On french version, the N number is in x axis, the Z is in y axis :

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactivit%C3%A9_%CE%B1#/media/Fichier:Modes_de_d%C3%A9sint%C3%A9gration_radioactive.svg

[image]

Comment: $A$ is not being plotted on $x$ or $y$  in either version. And you seem to have the axes backwards for the versions. Go look at the diagrams again. For the English, Z changes horizontally (x) and N changes vertically (y).

Comment: @Bill N : The x and y axes are not drawn because it translates from a svg format. Also, I was meaning N instead of A. I have fixed the question, which still makes sense : the two changes the axes choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On english version, the A number is in x axis, the Z is in y axis :

First, we should correct an error in your question. $A$ is not plotted on either axis.

The French wikipedia diagram coordinates with most [international charts of nuclides](http://atom.kaeri.re.kr/nuchart/) (also [here](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/) ), changing $Z$ vertically and $N$ horizontally. Most nuclear physics facilities which publish nuclide tables and charts do it this way.

While it's not incorrect to create the chart with $N$ vertical and $Z$ horizontal, it's not conventional. The only reason I can think of to do this is to make nuclide chart tall and narrow (portrait) for printing purposes, rather than shorter and wider (landscape).

By the way, constant $A$ groups (isobars) run diagonally, along the $\beta$-decay directions.

Comment: Everything is clear. Thank you @Bill N